# PowerShell - Most Compact way of "Delete all files from this folder except one"

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the most compact way of deleting all files from a folder *except* one file in a PowerShell script. I doesn't matter at all which file is kept, just as long as one is kept.

I'm using the PowerShell 2 CTP.

**UPDATE:**
An amalgamation of all the answers so far...

```
$fp = "\\SomeServer\SomeShare\SomeFolder"
gci $fp |where {$_.mode -notmatch "d"} |sort creationtime -desc |select -last ((@(gci $fp)).Length - 1) |del
```

Anybody see any issues with using this? How about the -notmatch part?

Comment: I don't have a problem per se with the -noMatch check. I think a more PS way would be where{ -not $_.PSIsContainer }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PS V2 we added `-SKIP` to Select so you could do:

```
dir | where {$_.mode -notmatch "d"} |select -skip 1 |del
```

Comment: This looks like it might be a great repository for formalized folklore.

Answer (score 5):

Without any built-in functions it is a little bit convoluted because the functions neeed to deal with definitive length.  But you can do it this way which involves looking at the directory twice

```
gci $dirName | select -last ((@(gci $dirName)).Length-1) | del
```

I wrote several powershell extensions that make tasks like this a lot easier.  One example is Skip-Count which allows for an arbitrary number of elements to be skipped in the pipeline.  So the code can be quickly searched to only look at the directory once

```
gci $dirName | skip-count 1 | del
```

Source to Skip-Count: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/13/linq-like-functions-for-powershell-skip-count.aspx

**EDIT**

In order to kill folders use "rm -re -fo" instead of "del"

**EDIT2**

In order to avoid all folders (empty or not) you can modify the code as such

```
gci $dirName | ?{ -not $_.PSIsContainer } | skip-count 1 | del
```

The PSISContainer member is only true for folders.

Comment: @EBGreen, no but I added an Edit to specify how to make it kill folders.

Comment: JaredPar, what exactly keeps it from deleting folders? See my last comments on zdans answer.

Comment: @Bruno, by default del will not delete a non-empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
dir $dirName | select -first ((dir $dirName).Length -1) | del
```

deletes all but the last one.

**Edit:** A more flexible version, plus you won't have to enter the dir command twice:

```
$include=$False; dir $dirNam | where {$include; $include=$True;} | del
```

Note, this does the opposite, it deletes all but the first. It also allows you to add clauses, such as to not act on directories:

```
$include=$False; dir $dirNam | where {$include -and $_.GetType() -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]; $include=$True;} | del
```

**Edit 2** with regards to excluding directories using the Mode property. I guess that should work provided that the framework does not change the way the mode string is generated (I can't imagine it will). Though I might tighten up the regular expression to:

```
$_.Mode -notmatch "^d.{4}"
```

If you are trying to avoid typing, adding a function to your profile is your best bet:

```
function isNotDir($file) { return $file.GetType() -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo];}
dir $dirName | where {isNotDir($_)}
```

Comment: How can you specify the path and make it all one line of code?

Comment: be aware that this one will delete folders as well.

Comment: I have edited this with a more flexible solution that will allow you to skip folders.

Comment: +1. I like where this is headed - especially the $_.GetType() -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo].  But when I try to use it I get an error (below)

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. + gci $dirName |where-object $_.GetType <<<< () -ne [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (GetType:String) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: would this work |where-object {$_.mode -notmatch "d"} or will that breakdown sometimes

Comment: @Bruno Tyndall: I think you forgot the braces for the where-object clause.

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, it would probably be better to use "$_.PSIsContainer".  Also, don't forget about the -is operator: $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]

Answer (score 1):

My favorite:

```
move file to preserve elsewhere
delete all files
move preserved file back
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dir $fp -Exclude "d" | del
```

Answer (score 0):

del *.* -Exclude (dir | sort creationtime -desc)[0] -whatif

This will delete all files except the most recently created.

Comment: I think that would leave a folder that is more recent than all the files.

Comment: hmmm. It would have to leave a single file. Folders/Subfolders need to stay untouched.